# Python: given a question, find one that is similar in database

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

I am writing a Telegram bot that answers to people's questions about a specific city. I wanted to write a piece of code that compares the message with the questions I have in my sqlite database table.

The biggest problem is that I cannot use `difflib.get_close_matches`, because **the questions are not in English** and at the moment I'm only handling exactly matching strings, for example:

```
if msg.lower() == "what can you do?":
    send_message("I can answer to any question you have about...", chat_id)
```

And that's definitely NOT my aim

So, let's get to the code: I'm using this function to get the last message

```
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN)

def get_updates(offset=None):
url = URL + "getUpdates"
if offset:
    url += "?offset={}".format(offset)
js = get_json_from_url(url)
return js
```

and assign the returned value to the variable `updates`, as a result I will have the message text in `update["message"]["text"]`

Now the difficult part, I would have to compare the string to the db records, then, if there is not any similar match, I will have to find synonyms of the words in the message and re-compare them to the records.

BUT this would make the program run awfully slow and I don't really have time nor will to make a list of synonyms for every possible word

Can anybody help me find the way to make a comparison and find a similar string in the db keeping the program as fast as possible?

Comment: suggestion for small kind of chatbots creation is use python and aiml, will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that probably there isn't a simple and easy way to go with something like this:

Since you're dealing with a database I will assume you have a wide range of possible questions, and that using a simple synonym table will not do

## [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) (NLP)

This is a very active research topic in Machine Learning and, in a nutshell, deals with automatically making sense from text. For your particular scenario. To get some intuition about it, and because it applies perfectly to your question, I would recommend starting with: [Question Similarity Calculation for FAQ Answering](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4438554/) by Song et al. (2007)

For a state-of-the-art tool that will help with your application, I suggest [word2vec](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781) (that's the paper, but you might also want to follow a [tutorial](http://kavita-ganesan.com/gensim-word2vec-tutorial-starter-code/).

## Other options

If NLP looks more complex than what you're aiming for, I would suggest looking at word similarities, such as:

- [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)
- [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)

These, however, will not perform as well as a well trained NLP system.